# sqlite3.OperationalError: near "?": syntax error when looping through pragma table_info

Tags: python, sqlite

I want to validate the tables and views of a database entered by a user are configured properly before I start to perform CRUD operations on it.

I can get the this to work if I hard code each of the table names, but I want to dynamically collect info on all tables and views to be more efficient and to know if there are more than I expect.

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect("test.db")
tables = c.execute("""SELECT name 
                          FROM sqlite_master 
                          WHERE type='view' 
                          OR type='table' 
                          ORDER BY name;""").fetchall()
for t in tables:
    c.execute("pragma table_info(?)",t).fetchall()
```

The output of the "tables" looks like this:

```
[('table1',), ('table2',), ('v_view1',)]
```

When I run the code above it returns the error below.

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "?": syntax error
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `?` variables only for values, not for identifiers such as table names.

Use string formatting to produce an SQL string with the table name in it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for t in tables:
   c.execute("pragma table_info({})".format(t)).fetchall()
```